# Присвоение переменной os.system('clear')

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь вызвать переменную `clear` со значением `os.system('clear')`. При вызове ничего не происходит. Как можно исправить?

```
import os; clear = os.system('clear')
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо указать ОС, а то в Windows такой команды нет. Ну и заодно какого поведения ожидаете.

Answer (score 3):

> вызвать переменную clear со значением os.system('clear')

Что, простите?

*"вызвать переменную"* нельзя, можно вызвать функцию. Вы вызываете функцию `os.system` с аргументом-строкой `'clear'`.

> При вызове ничего не происходит. Как можно исправить?

Чего не происходит? У меня все происходит: консоль очищается, в переменную `clear` попадает код возврата команды (соответственно, 0). Если у вас это не так, пишите подробнее, что не происходит. Когда *"ничего не происходит"*, говорят, что компьютер завис и нужен хард-ресет.

> `import os; clear = os.system('clear')`

Есть смутное подозрение, что вы хотите не `clear = os.system('clear')`, а `clear = lambda: os.system('clear')`. Это так? Опишите подробнее, что должно происходить?

Comment: У меня почему-то не очищается консоль.

Comment: А что за ОС? И что возвращает, собственно, clear? 0?

Comment: Linux. если через print(), то ноль. А так просто продолжается работа скрипта.

Comment: @CockLobster: дополнительную информацию, которая может помочь ответить на вопрос следует в сам вопрос добавить (комментарии предназначены только для временной информации) -- кнопка [править](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/439176/edit) под вопросом. Что происходит, если запустить `python -c'import os; print("before"); os.system("clear"); print("after")'`?